Convert double rocker switch into single digital timer - how to make this work
I'm trying to convert this double rocker switch into a single switch with a digital timer. This switch controls my spa and pool lights and want them to turn on and off at specific hours. It also appears there is another wire running from the breaker that is soldered to the inside of the box, which I presume is either the neutral or ground, but unsure. It's worth noting that my home was built in the 70s.
Update: Thank you all for the comments. I've purchased a Honeywell 7-day 120v 7 day timer (no neutral required). Link to below Let me know if this will work.
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004SOZHR0?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title
I've attached additonal images of the switch and box. Thanks again.





Need better pictures of the sides of the switch and inside of the box.  This is not a site for hire so get rid of that before it gets deleted.

@JACK 100%. And Rob: $200 is typical in a lot of places in the US, and then finding an electrician who will actually do the small job is even harder sometimes. In or near any major city it will typically be at least $100 just to walk through the door so $200 for "straighten out old wiring to a switch and replace it" is typical.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact wrong comment, nobody asked about prices

@Traveler If you look at the Edit History, you will see that OP did mention pricing as a concern, which JACK recommended removing, I agreed, and 3Phase correctly and appropriately removed.

Tie the 2 wires to the spa and the pool together with a "pigtail".
On the new timer switch attach that pigtail to the "load" wire or screw. Attach the Hot lead to the "Hot in" or "Power " side of the switch. ( probably the yellow wire, but check to be sure what wires are to loads and which carries the power ) Ground to ground wire or the metal box. Neutral to neutral."
White wire"
You may not have a neutral in the box. That will be the issue. Either you need to run a new neutral through the conduit, or get a timer that does not need a neutral.

Based on colors this may be conduit and likely no neutral in the box currently.

@man, Yeah I figure that. I had to post my answer then go to the pic and blow it up to see if I could discern  if one was there.

If the new timer has a load wire (and no screw), then that wire could serve as the pigtail and directly connect to the 2 wires of the spa.

Thank you all. I've updated the post with picture and timer above. Please let me know if you have any additonal guidance. I will attempt the install later this evening.
